# How to define a firefox binary path with robot framework?

Tags: selenium, firefox, path, webdriver, robotframework

I'm new to Robot Framework, I have tried setting the path to the Firefox binary through Robot Framework without success. My goal is to parse the following python code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

 binary = FirefoxBinary('c:\path\to\binary')
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

with robot framework:

```
${firefox_path}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path="C:\\Users\\xxx\\ff\\firefox.exe", log_file=None)    sys
Create WebDriver    Firefox    firefox_binary=${firefox_path}
Go to    www.google.fr
```

However when I run the above I get the following error message:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to
find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability
provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix my problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, two days of trying to get Firefox to work.

Thanks, Nelly

Comment: can you share version of browser what you are using now?

Comment: I used firefox 52.0.2 installed version, and now I want to use the same version of firefox portable.

Comment: Please note that Firefox portable is not recommended (supported) by geckodriver. Instead of trying to set capabilities, why don't you try to set the PATH environment variable to find portable first?

Comment: I am aware that firefox portable is not recommanded.The path env variable runs fine for one firefox but I have several firefox portable versions on my machine

Comment: This looks correct to me as far as converting from Py to RF code. Have you tried doing it directly in Python?

Comment: Hi ombre42, I've tried in Python and it doesn't work with portable firefox version unlike the installed version

Answer (score 1):

I share with you one solution :

If you want to test Firefox Extended Support Release or portable Firefox, you just have to set the marionette to false

```
${firefox_path}= | Evaluate | sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary(firefox_path='C:\\Users\\xxx\\FirefoxPortable37\\FirefoxPortable.exe', log_file=None) | sys
${caps}= | Evaluate | sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX | sys
Set To Dictionary | ${caps} | marionette=${False}
Create WebDriver | Firefox | firefox_binary=${firefox_path} | capabilities=${caps}
Go To | http://free.fr
```